# Linux curl not working

Tags: linux, curl, networking, proxy

I am trying to access a remote server which responds properly in one network but not in another. I can access it on my local machine(In some networks) but not on aws:

Working Curl:

```
curl -vvv https://abc.example.com -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' --user ******:***** -d '<XML></XML>'
```

Output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* Connected to abc.example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=**; ST=***; L=***; x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x=**; x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x=ABCD; x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x=def; O=abc def ghi; businessCategory=abc def; serialNumber=123456; CN=abc.example.com
*    start date: 2016-04-04 07:19:41 GMT
*    expire date: 2018-04-04 07:49:39 GMT
*    subjectAltName: abc.example.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '******'
> POST /abc/def HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic *********************
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: abc.example.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/xml
> Content-Length: 16783
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 07:31:25 GMT
* Server Oracle-Application-Server-11g is not blacklisted
< Server: Oracle-Application-Server-11g
< X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: *************************
< SOAPAction: "http://ghi.services//abc"
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
<XML>SUCCESSFUL OUTPUT</XML>
```

Not working CURL:

```
curl -vvv https://abc.example.com -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' --user ******:***** -d '<XML></XML>'
```

Output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* Connected to abc.example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=XX; ST=XXXXXXX; L=XXXXXXX; x.x.x.x.x.x.x=XX; x.x.x.x.x.x.x=XXXXXXX; x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x=XXXXX; O=Some company name; businessCategory=My unit; serialNumber=12345; CN=abc.example.com
*    start date: 2016-04-04 07:19:41 GMT
*    expire date: 2018-04-04 07:49:39 GMT
*    subjectAltName: abc.example.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '**********'
> POST /abc/def HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic ******************
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: abc.example.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/xml
> Content-Length: 16783
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 07:37:47 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 226
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

I don't have any idea what's going on. Please help

Comment: Are you trying to run the curl from an EC2 instance? if so, can you communicate with other urls through this instance? is this instance running in a VPC?

Comment: Yes, i am running this curl from an EC2 instance. Yes, i can communicate with other urls through this instance. No, this instance is not running in VPC.